# SideEffects in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

I understood that other than the act of `composition` in `composable`, all other actions were side effects. So, in the case of `TextField`, is changing the `TextFieldValue` in `onValueChange` a side effect? Also, is it a side effect to display a toast message in `composable`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's first understand few terms w.r.t functional programming

`Idempotent` -  means calling the same function n times, providing the same input, should result in same output.

Your function needs to be `idempotent` in compose world, for the recomposition to work - as compose runtime, `memoizes` during initial composition, and if during recomposition the input of the function have't changed (or say the tree node isn't updated), compose runtime will use the same `memoized` result. Having a function not being `idempotent` will lead to unexpected behaviour during recomposition.

`Purefunction` - Functions that don't contain side-effect.

`Side-effect` - it's any action that escapes the scope of the function to do something unexpected on the side.

```
In compose world - side-effect could be a change to the state of the app that happens outside of the scope of the function, things like setting a global variable, updating cache, making a network query, reading from file etc.. 

It makes the function non-deterministic and can lead to race condition and unexpected behavior. 

To generalize, side-effects are unexpected actions happening on the side, out of what callers would expect from the function, and that alter its behavior.
```

As we say a function should be side-effect free, however in few scenarios we need to run a side-effect from composable, to handle those cases compose run-time provides different [effect-handlers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects), - which will makes sure, they run at the right time with accordance to the compose lifecycle.

> So, in the case of TextField, is changing the TextFieldValue in
> onValueChange a side effect?

It more looks like an [unidirectional](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) data flow to me and the since the state is managed within the scope of composable (internal memory of composable), it's not a side-effect.

> Also, is it a side effect to display a toast message in composable?

It can be a side-effect, if the effect is not handled properly, considering, you are not ending up getting the toast called, on ever recomposition.

Answer (score 3):

According to defination of SideEffect in Jetpack Compose, A side-effect is a change to the state of the app that happens outside the scope of a composable function.
In TextField, we can't change state of textfield we swape the value.
You can see it in CoreTextField Compose funtion:

```
            if (value != it) {
                onValueChange(it)
            }
        },
```

So in onValueChange, no SideEffects use.

Also in the case of Toast message, yet Toast is not written in Compose so it is not a compose function and we can call it from outside of compose function so there is no side effect use.