# How to make calls(database, network) in composable functions?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

If I am going to use 1 activity for the whole app with no fragments.
Navigation will be done using compose functions.
How I can do read/edit database or get activity context or do networks call in the compose functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can do read/edit database or do networks call in the compose functions

This is a side-effect and i recommend doing it the viewModel via callback in your composables. But, if there's a scenario where you want to handle these side-effects in the composable, in that case you should use [effect-handlers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects?authuser=1).

You can work through this [code-lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fcompose%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fjetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#0) to understand the different side-effects being used in different scenarios, in your case i am assuming `rememberCoroutineScope` should do, if using coroutine or other effects like `DisposableEffect` if using `RxJava` or any other threading framework, one which fits your use-case from the effect-handlers.

Here, i have explained [side-effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233520/sideeffects-in-jetpack-compose/69243650#69243650) in compose, [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects?authuser=1) is a great resource for looking into it.

> or get activity context?

Activity context are implicity provided to the composables via providers, i.e. they are added in the root node of the composable and child nodes can access them via providers.

If you need something like context you can get it via `LocalContext`

```
LocalContext.current
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal?authuser=1) you can read about it more on other `CompositionLocal` which are implicity provided to each composables.